# Read Excel file throw FormCollection MVC

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read excel file.I have **razor view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportData", "Sourced", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult ImportData(FormCollection formCollection)

 HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadFile"];
 byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
```

But when I have this fileBytes all of them is zero.I read all of the thinks in internet and I do not have a solution.

Comment: Can you please check the Id of file which you have given in the view and try using it.

Comment: Yes I `m using the file ID with the same name.I have the write FileName but the file byte are empty

Comment: Can you share your .cshtml code for fileupload